# MySQL data in JSON format to js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have DataTables table with data from one mysql table and after click on table row, I need to show data from another mysql table. I'm sending the data from both tables in JSON. I have this script (jsfiddle) and this is the php script to get the data from DB:

```
<?php

$tic = $_POST['name'];

$conn = mysqli_connect("192.168.2.11", "admin", "pass", "mydb");

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT TIME, DESC FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.ACTION=ACT AND ID='" . $tic . "'");

// storing in array
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
        $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);

// FOLLOWING CODE WORKS WITH THE CODE IN FIDDLE..
/*
echo json_encode( [
    "html" => 'Details for <b>'.htmlentities($_POST['name']) . '<br><p>
] );
*/

$conn->close();
?>
```

This is my JSON I need to show in row details in table:

```
[
    {"TIME":"2016-05-24 04:48:25","DESC":"Created"},
    {"TIME":"2016-06-25 07:53:36","DESC":"Completion"}
]
```

I need to show the data from second ajax call in the **format** function and I need to style them to tables (not another datatable), because there will be more data in the future. I tried to modify format function and return rowData[0], but it returns data from 1st table, not the row details. Thanks

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/4m81pp4m/)

Comment: I see vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: Thanks Ntwobike, I'll have to check the security issues when it will work correctly.